# Strange hibernate behavior: null list instead of empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The Db schema is this: [image]
When I run the `findMonitorUserById(userId)` function, hibernate should return a list containing the `MonitoredUsers` associated with the `MonitorUser` with `id=userId`. Within each `MonitoredUser` I have two lists: `takeList` and `isMonitoredByList`. By default I should always have a collection at most empty but never null right?
By debugging I see that, indeed this statement is respected for the `takeList` but not for the `isMonitoredByList`. Is this due to an error on my part?  To configuration problems?

Here is the implementation:

Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

@Autowired
IUserService userService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/addMonitoredUser", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Transactional(rollbackOn = SaveException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<MonitorUserDTO> addMonitoredUser(@RequestBody MonitoredUserDTO monitoredUserDTO) throws DrugNotFoundException, SaveException, UserNotFoundException {

        MonitorUser monitorUser = userService.findMonitorUserById(monitoredUserDTO.getMonitorUser().getId());
        MonitorUserDTO monitorUserDTO = setMonitorDTO(monitorUser);

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .body(monitorUserDTO);
    }

}
```

If I inspect monitorUser i can see:

[image]

UserService.java

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public MonitorUser findMonitorUserById(int idUser) throws UserNotFoundException {
        MonitorUser res = userRepository.findMonitorUserById(idUser);

        if(res == null)
            throw new UserNotFoundException("UserService findMonitorUserById(" +idUser +"): not found");
        return res;
    }
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    MonitorUser findMonitorUserById(int idMonitor);

}
```

And, finally, here are the entity class:

MonitorUser.java.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("monitor")
public class MonitorUser extends User{
    public MonitorUser() {
    }

    String username;
    String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "monitorUser", targetEntity = Monitor.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    List<Monitor> monitorList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "monitorUser", targetEntity = MonitoredUser.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<MonitoredUser> monitoredUserList;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Monitor> getMonitorList() {
        return monitorList;
    }

    public void setMonitorList(List<Monitor> monitorList) {
        this.monitorList = monitorList;
    }

    public List<MonitoredUser> getMonitoredUserList() {
        return monitoredUserList;
    }

    public void setMonitoredUserList(List<MonitoredUser> monitoredUserList) {
        this.monitoredUserList = monitoredUserList;
    }
}
```

MonitoredUser.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("monitored")
public class MonitoredUser extends User{
    public MonitoredUser() {
    }

    float weight;
    int height; //in cm
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Gender sex;
    boolean smoker;
    String phoneNumber;
    int nyhaclass;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "monitoredUser", targetEntity = Take.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    List<Take> takeList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "monitoredUser", targetEntity = IsMonitoredBy.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    List<IsMonitoredBy> isMonitoredByList;
    boolean hospitalized;
    @ManyToOne
    MonitorUser monitorUser;

    //and all the getter and setter

}
```

IsMonitoredBy.java

```
@Entity

public class IsMonitoredBy {

    public IsMonitoredBy() {
    }

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    int id;
    long lastSyncTimeStamp;

    @ManyToOne
    MonitoredUser monitoredUser;
    @ManyToOne
    Device device;

    long timestampStart;
    long timestampEnd;

//all the getter an setter
}
```

Comment: The field is lazy loaded. What happens if you access it, does it get a value? The contents themselves may only get loaded once you try to access the list itself, e.g. call `size()` or try to access an element.

Comment: it returns null, I also tried to set eager but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: IsMonitoredBy class is not correctly annotated as JPA Entity because it is followed by an empty line.

Comment: @Mar-z it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead!!

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    List<MonitorUser> findMonitorUserById(int idMonitor);

}
```

Comment: How can it resolve the problem, the id is the primary key it must not return a list.
Every monitor sholud have their own MonitoredUser. The second one is a list

Comment: Moreover, takeList returns what I expect it to return, so the problem should be related to MonitoredUser and IsMonitoredBy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).